# How to get page_id from facebook url

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-graph-api

my question is how get facebook page_id starting from a simple fb url. For example:

- http://www.facebook.com/**vanityurl**
- http://www.facebook.com/pages/pagename/**pageid**

Actually if the url match the string "facebook.com/pages/" I call:

- https://graph.facebook.com/**pageid**

else I call:

- https://graph.facebook.com/**vanityurl**

This approach seems to work well, but it is really empirical and looking at documentation I don't see any suggestion.
What do you think about?

Comment: In most cases you'll already have the page ID from another API call, right? (from a user's feed, or list of likes, etc?) - otherwise the method you've outlined above is the best I can think of

Comment: Actually I only have a list of urls which I have to investigate for.

Comment: @freedev your question is your answer, this is the best way I know of and I am using the same too..

Answer (score 8):

Simple Instructions:

1. Go to the desired Facebook page
2. Ctrl + U to view Page Source
3. Ctrl + F to open a search dialog box
4. Using the search dialog box, search "page_id=" in the code
5. The 'page_id' should follow the "=" symbol

TEST:

Search for the desired page using the 'page_id' in place of the page name:

www.facebook.com/**[insert 'page_id' here]**

Comment: This worked for me. Just one thing I was able to get page id by searching "pageid" not "page_id".

Answer (score 6):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking but I think what you're talking about is trying to get the id of a page that you only know by its "vanity url" or "nickname".

Basically you can do a facebook graph api request to the "vanity url" and then grab the id from the provided request.

For example... if you open the Facebook graph API explorer 
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=coca.cola.

or make a request to http://graph.facebook.com/coca.cola

you can see in the response you get 
  "id": "40796308305"
which is the page ID you are talking about.

Navigating to http://www.facebook.com/40796308305 should prove that.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For my OG meta `<meta property="fb:app_id" content="010101010101010" />`

I got my page app id by going here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin

get code > appId

Line 6: `js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.9&appId=
010101010101010";`

The sharing debugger has now stopped complaining
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/